# Javascript ES6 Promise error "Uncaught (in promise)"

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm getting an error on Chrome Console, I do not fully understand what could be the reason.

Here is my sample code:

```
function sayHi() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log('Hi')
        reject('Not in the mood')
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve()
        }, 20)
    })
}

sayHi().then(() => {
    console.log('Bye')
})
```

If you run this code on console you will see the Promise being rejected, which is an expected outcome. However, there is also an error message:

> Uncaught (in promise) Bye Promise.then (async) (anonymous) @
>   VM374412:11

This error message won't be there if `reject` is removed from the `sayHi` function. But that must not be the intention of any developer to not have `reject` at all.

Are we supposed to ignore the error message, or is there something I have totally missed out?

Thanks.

Comment: you're not handling the rejection, therefore you get the message

Comment: add `.catch(e => console.log('rejection', e))` after your .then, and magically no warning about unhandled rejection, since you are now handling the rejection

Comment: How to do that in this sample code?

Comment: I just told you the code to add ... `sayHi().then(() => {
    console.log('Bye')
})` `.catch(e => console.log('rejection', e))`

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you, I got it. Is there no way without handling the rejection?

Comment: @DonnieAshok Why wouldn't you want to handle the rejection?

Comment: you want to avoid warning about unhandled rejection, but you don't want to handle a rejection? you dont' have to actually do anything in the .catch ... you could `.catch(() => {})` if you want - so now there's no indication at all of a rejection - but ... why? The problem with such minimal and meaningless code is, there's so many possibilities of what real world code would actually do, that it's hard to give you a definitive answer that will help with real code - i.e. you don't need to handle rejections at every point in the promise chain